# What can I add/change with the following query to help me get the last 5 games per player?

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to calculate each player's average stats, per 28 minutes, over their respective last 5 games of the 2021-2022 regular season using the following column structure: PLAYER_ID, FGM, FGA, FG3M, FG3A, FTM, FTA, OREB, DREB, REB, AST, TOV, STL, BLK, BLKA, PF, PFD, PTS, PLUS_MINUS, FG_PCT, FG3_PCT, FT_PCT.

the query I started with was

```
SELECT
    PLAYER_NAME, PLAYER_ID, AVG(FGM) as FGM, AVG(FGA) as FGA, AVG(FG3M) as FG3M,
        AVG(FG3A) as FG3A, AVG(FTM) as FTM, AVG(FTA) as FTA, AVG(OREB) as OREB, 
        AVG(DREB) as DREB, AVG(REB) as REB, AVG(AST) as AST, AVG(TOV) as TOV, AVG(STL) as STL,
        AVG(BLK) as BLK, AVG(BLKA) as BLKA, AVG(PF) as PF, AVG(PFD) as PFD, AVG(PTS) as PTS, 
        AVG(PLUS_MINUS) as PLUS_MINUS, AVG(FG_PCT) as FG_PCT, AVG(FG3_PCT) as FG3_PCT, AVG(FT_PCT) as 
        FT_PCT
FROM
    sis_basketball_research.nba_player_game_logs
GROUP BY
    PLAYER_NAME, PLAYER_ID
HAVING
    AVG(MIN) >= 28;
```

I am not totally sure that this is the correct way to run this query and I also still need to add something to it to only pull the last 5 games for each player. Have been struggling on this for a while so I would appreciate any help given.

I have tried changing the query to the below but it only limits to 5 rows instead of 5 games per player:

```
SELECT 
    game_date,
    PLAYER_NAME, PLAYER_ID,
    AVG(FGM) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS FGM_avg_28_min,
    AVG(FGA) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS FGA_avg_28_min,
    AVG(FG3M) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS FG3M_avg_28_min,
    AVG(FG3A) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS FG3A_avg_28_min,
    AVG(FTM) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS FTM_avg_28_min,
    AVG(FTA) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS FTA_avg_28_min,
    AVG(OREB) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS OREB_avg_28_min,
    AVG(DREB) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS DREB_avg_28_min,
    AVG(REB) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS REB_avg_28_min,
    AVG(AST) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS AST_avg_28_min,
    AVG(TOV) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS TOV_avg_28_min,
    AVG(STL) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS STL_avg_28_min,
    AVG(BLK) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS BLK_avg_28_min,
    AVG(BLKA) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS BLKA_avg_28_min,
    AVG(PF) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS PF_avg_28_min,
    AVG(PFD) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS PFD_avg_28_min,
    AVG(PTS) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS PTS_avg_28_min,
    AVG(PLUS_MINUS) / (SUM(MIN) / 28) AS PLUS_MINUS_avg_28_min,
    AVG(FG_PCT) AS FG_PCT_avg,
    AVG(FG3_PCT) AS FG3_PCT_avg,
    AVG(FT_PCT) AS FT_PCT_avg
FROM
    sis_basketball_research.nba_player_game_logs
GROUP BY
    PLAYER_NAME, PLAYER_ID, game_date
ORDER BY
    GAME_DATE DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: What you’re looking for is called a RANK query.

Comment: @J_H I have never written a RANK query before. Very new to this and trying to continue learning the ropes. Any suggestions on where to look for examples?

Comment: I have not yet searched google for sql RANK, so IDK maybe such a search would come up empty. But every other time I consulted google there was at least one line of example code available. StackOverflow wants you to post an answer here if you’re able to answer your own question.